# Setting foreign key id to null in EF is very VERY slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework through a Repositories pattern and have a significant and surprising performance problem. I have done profiling so I have a pretty good idea of what happens, I just don't know what to do about it.

Here is the essense of my code (simplified):

```
var employee = Repositories.Employees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EmployeeId == employeeId);
employee.CompanyId = null;
Repositories.Commit();
```

The middle line (`employee.CompanyId = null`) takes an astounding amount of time to complete (around 30 seconds). The time is NOT spent on the Commit line.

Through profiling, I have found the reason to be running this part of the auto generated EF code:

```
if (previousValue != null && previousValue.**Employees**.Contains(this))
{
    previousValue.Employees.Remove(this);
}
```

That doesn't really help me, but it does confirm that the problem lies in the EF. I would really like to know what to do. I can update the column in other ways (stored procedure) but I would really rather use the EF everywhere.

I cannot easily edit the EF settings, so I would prefer suggestions that does not involve this.

**Update**
I solved the problem by running SQL directly against the database and then refreshing the object from context to make sure EF would detect this change immediately.

```
public void SetCompanyNull(Guid employeeId)
{
    _ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE Employee SET CompanyId = NULL WHERE EmployeeId = N'" + employeeId + "'");
    _ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, _ctx.Employees.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EmployeeId == employeeId));
}
```

**Update 2**
I ALSO solved the problem by disabling lazy loading temporarily.

```
var lazyLoadDisabled = false;
if (_ctx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled)
{
   _ctx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   lazyLoadDisabled = true;
}

this.GetEmployeeById(employeeId).CompanyId = null;
this.SaveChanges();

if (lazyLoadDisabled)
{
    _ctx.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

I am really curious about WHY it's so much faster with lazy loading disabled (and which side-effects this might have)

Comment: As it turned out, disabling lazy loading, even temporarily, had consequences elsewhere and I could not use that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is problem in EF POCO Generator Template which causes unexpected lazy loading in some scenarios. This template generates fixup code for navigation properties so if you change the navigation property on one side it internally goes to other end of the changed relation and tries to fix the relation to be still consistent. Unfortunately if your related object doesn't have navigation property loaded it triggers lazy loading.

What you can do:

- Modify template and remove all code related to fixup
- Remove reverse navigation property (`Employees`) from your `Company`
- Turn off lazy loading prior to this operation - `context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`

Comment: Turning off Lazy Loading worked wonders! It is more or less as fast as running SQL directly against the database. With lazy loading disabled, what happens/doesn't happen that makes it perform so much faster?

Comment: It will not load all employees for the company where you removed selected employee.

Comment: As I understand lazy loading, it means it will only load something once it NEEDS it. However, I am DISABLING lazy loading, which means it must be running in **eager** loading which, to me, sounds like that's when it would 'eagerly' load all employees even though it doesn't need them (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is strange; on the otherhand, instead of setting companyId to null; you may try to remove it from the collection. Something like;

```
var company = Repositories.Companies.Include("Employee").FirstOrDefault(s => s.Employee.Any(q => q.EmployeeId == employeeId));
company.Employees.Remove(q => company.Employees.Where(l => l.EmployeeId == employeeId).SingleOrDefault());
Repositories.Commit();
```

Comment: I think this shows very well what the EF is actually doing behind the scenes - getting the entire "Employees" list just to remove one item from it. The problem is, in my case, the "Employees" list contains thousands of records - perhaps that's why it take so much time.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with automatic change detecttion.

As pointed out by Ladislav Mrnka, when you change a property involved in a relation, it will try to transfer the change to the related entities.

You can avoid this by disabling automatic "Change Tracking" on your context while you execute that operation.

This explains a similar problem an its solution:

- [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 12: Automatically Detecting Changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/06/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-12-automatically-detecting-changes.aspx)

An this explains the Chaneg Tracking concept in general:

- [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696177%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)